# symfony and composer are installed in the wrong place

Tags: symfony, composer-php, wamp

I have installed Composer and Symfony with cmd, but the cmd force me to install in C:/users/anthony. The problem ? %y wamp is in `C/wamp64/www` :') 
What is the best thing to do now?
Thank you.

Comment: What's the exact problem with all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cmd and use the command `cd C:/wamp64/www`. It will bring you to that location.

After it, use `composer install`.